# Sherlock software InnoTool Downloader helper proxy support

Tags: proxy, inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

[InnoTools Downloader](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50), is a great tool for downloading files during installation.

Is there a way to support proxy settings with a download?

In the release notes from 2008, it says something about [" - Preliminary support for proxy server autodetection"](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=56).

I could not find anything in the [help](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/innotools/itdhelp/index.html) files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InnoTools downloader uses the [`InternetQueryOption` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetqueryoptionw) (with `dwOption` = `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY`) to autodetect proxy to be used.

There's no way to explicitly configure proxy.

---

On the other hand, the [Inno Download Plugin](https://mitrichsoftware.wordpress.com/inno-setup-tools/inno-download-plugin/) (that you've tagged your question with) does support explicit proxy configuration:

```pascal
procedure idpSetProxyMode(mode: String);             external 'idpSetProxyMode@files:idp.dll cdecl';
procedure idpSetProxyName(name: String);             external 'idpSetProxyName@files:idp.dll cdecl';
procedure idpSetProxyLogin(login, password: String); external 'idpSetProxyLogin@files:idp.dll cdecl';
```

---

[DwinsHs (Downloader for Inno Setup)](https://www.han-soft.com/dwinshs.php) also supports proxy.

---

I do not have any experience with either, but InnoTools downloader has not been updated since 2008, while Inno Download Plugin and DwinsHs seem to be still maintained.